# Asp Net MVC with VM is this good practice? (Code Sample)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm wondering if what I have here is good practice. Using Entity Framework Code First with MVC and View Models.
Below i have code for List, Create, Edit and Delete. Model name Page and 2 ViewModels name ContentViewModel and ContentListViewModel.

```
 private readonly IUserService _userService;
    //private readonly MembershipProvider _members;

    public ContentController()
    {
        // _members = Membership.Provider;
        _userService = new AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Profile/Content/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var db = new BlogContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Page> pages;
            pages = db.ArticlePages.ToList();
            List<ContentListViewModel> model = new List<ContentListViewModel>();
            foreach (Page pg in pages)
            {
                MembershipUser user = _userService.Get(pg.authorId);
                model.Add(new ContentListViewModel()
                {
                    PageID = pg.pageID,
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    UserID = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey,
                    IsFrontPage = pg.frontpage,
                    isPublished = pg.published,
                    PageTitle = pg.titleHeading,
                    PageUrlName = pg.idName,
                    PublishedDate = pg.datentime
                });
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Profile/Content/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Profile/Content/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ContentViewModel page)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new BlogContext())
            {
                db.ArticlePages.Add(new Page()
                {
                    authorId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey,
                    datentime = DateTime.Now,
                    frontpage = page.FrontPage,
                    published = page.Published,
                    titleHeading = page.TitleHeading,
                    pageContent = page.Content,
                    idName = page.IdName
                });
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index").Success("Page added Successfully.");
            }
        }

        return View(page);
    }


    //
    // GET: /Profile/Content/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        if (id == 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index").Error("Page Not found.");
        }
        Page pg = new Page();
        using (var db = new BlogContext())
        {
            pg = (from m in db.ArticlePages where m.pageID == id select m).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        if (pg == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index").Error("Page Not found..");
        }
        return View(new ContentViewModel()
        {
            id = pg.pageID,
            Content = pg.pageContent,
            FrontPage = pg.frontpage,
            Published = pg.published,
            TitleHeading = pg.titleHeading,
            IdName = pg.idName
        });
    }


    // POST: /Profile/Content/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ContentViewModel page)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new BlogContext())
            {
                var oPage = db.ArticlePages.Single(p => p.pageID == page.id);
                oPage.frontpage = page.FrontPage;
                oPage.idName = page.IdName;
                oPage.pageContent = page.Content;
                oPage.published = page.Published;
                oPage.titleHeading = page.TitleHeading;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index").Success("Page updated");
            }
        }
        return View(page);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Profile/Content/Delete/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new BlogContext())
        {
            Page page = db.ArticlePages.Find(id);
            db.ArticlePages.Remove(page);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index").Success("Page deleted");
        }
    }
```

I would like to know there are better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

While that method is certainly better than passing the entities directly to the view, I would suggest a number of improvements.

First, I would create a new business layer, and then create a facade class to retrieve your data.  Then move all database access to this layer.  Thus, you would end up with a call to the service layer rather than doing direct database access like you are doing above.

Second, you should look into using something like AutoMapper to map between your data entities and your view models.